# Understanding timescales within the day period

Tags: oceanography

I stumbled across a timescale which I am unsure of. What does it mean by intra-daily scale variability? I would also like to know if intra-tidal scale variability is of any use for capturing **daily** physical processes in estuaries (e.g. stratification). Feedback will help me understand when it is appropriate to use these timescales for making scientific predictions.

Comment: You might benefit for exploring flood-ebb asymmetry: http://www.coastalwiki.org/wiki/Tidal_asymmetry_and_tidal_basin_morphodynamics

Answer (score 1):

Intra-daily scale variability is pointing to the circadian rhythms. the circadian rhythms are physical, mental, and behavioral changes that follow a "daily" cycle. They respond primarily to light and darkness in an organism's environment. It is not an accurate time scale, as the light and darkness are not a cycle itself, but it is commonly use on medicine. Google it. I will recommend [this.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5533453/)

The Intra-tidal it is used for a few processes linked with the tides, but it is not "just" on daily basis as the tides have not a daily interval. Look [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tide) and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunitidal_interval)

Both timescales are usefull for whatever process linked to human (or animal) bodies and tides. But as scale times, they are not very useful.

Regarding predictions... which kind of predictions are you talking about?

Comment: Want to understand how stratification of an estuary could change during the ebb/flood phase and its characteristics. I only got one day on a research cruise in the Irish Sea. That is why I mentioned **daily** intervals.

Comment: On salt-wedge estuaries it is possible if you exposed on small section of the ground level in the low tide, as you will find a strong stratification. But even, it will depends of the rain (it is a problem on the Irish Sea), on the water-evaporation (not an issue), fresh water flow (depends of the estuary)... alternative way is try to search for any civil or building works close to the estuary and take a look to whatever trench they have there. Any how, you can see the deposition but you need a long term observation series to make any prediction.